# De-mojibaking with Python and mutagen

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, mojibake, mutagen

I'm reading mojibaked ID3 tags with `mutagen`. My goal is to fix the mojibake while learning about encodings and Python's handling thereof.

The file I'm working with has an `ID3v2` tag, and I'm looking at its album (`TALB`) frame, which is, according to the encoding byte in the `TALB` ID3 frame, encoded in Latin-1 (`ISO-8859-1`). I know that the bytes in this frame, however, are encoded in `cp1251` (Cyrillic).

Here's my code so far:

```
 >>> from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
 >>> mp3 = MP3(paths[0])
 >>> mp3['TALB']
 TALB(encoding=0, text=[u'\xc1\xf3\xf0\xe6\xf3\xe9\xf1\xea\xe8\xe5 \xef\xeb\xff\xf1\xea\xe8'])
```

Now, as you can see, `mp3['TALB'].text[0]` is represented here as a Unicode string. However, it's mojibaked:

```
 >>> print mp3['TALB'].text[0]
 Áóðæóéñêèå ïëÿñêè
```

I am having very little luck at transcoding these `cp1251` bytes into their correct Unicode codepoints. My best results so far have been very unbecoming:

```
>>> st = ''.join([chr(ord(x)) for x in mp3['TALB'].text[0]]); st
'\xc1\xf3\xf0\xe6\xf3\xe9\xf1\xea\xe8\xe5 \xef\xeb\xff\xf1\xea\xe8'
>>> print st.decode('cp1251')
Буржуйские пляски <-- **this is the correct, demojibaked text!**
```

As I understand this approach, it works because I end up transforming the Unicode string into an 8-bit string, which I can then decode into Unicode, while specifying the encoding I am decoding from.

The problem is that I can't `decode('cp1251')` on the Unicode string directly:

```
>>> st = mp3['TALB'].text[0]; st
u'\xc1\xf3\xf0\xe6\xf3\xe9\xf1\xea\xe8\xe5 \xef\xeb\xff\xf1\xea\xe8'
>>> print st.decode('cp1251')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dmitry/dev/mp3_tag_encode_convert/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1251.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone explain this? I can't understand how to make it not decode into the 7-bit `ascii` range when operating directly on the `u''` string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, encode it in the encoding that you know it is already in.

```
>>> tag = u'\xc1\xf3\xf0\xe6\xf3\xe9\xf1\xea\xe8\xe5 \xef\xeb\xff\xf1\xea\xe8'
>>> raw = tag.encode('latin-1'); raw
'\xc1\xf3\xf0\xe6\xf3\xe9\xf1\xea\xe8\xe5 \xef\xeb\xff\xf1\xea\xe8'
```

Then you can decode it in the proper encoding.

```
>>> fixed = raw.decode('cp1251'); print fixed
Буржуйские пляски
```

Comment: Heh! Interesting! Thank you very much! I guess I didn't think of that as practically the same thing I was doing because I don't really understand this encode step you provided. I've got a Unicode string from mutagen (why does mutagen output Unicode when the tag specified 8-bit? I don't know). I'm encoding this Unicode it into a Latin-1 string. Since all the bytes are in the 8-bit range, what's the practical difference between the strings when I try `decode('cp1251)` on them? Why does decoding from Unicode fail?

Comment: It fails because `u''.decode(enc)` is the same as `u''.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).decode(enc)`, and `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is almost always `== 'ascii'`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification you provided Francis. To clarify my other point of confusion regarding the encode('latin-1') step—I'm not sure **logically** why I'd want to encode into Latin-1 first. Someone used `cp1251`, while the ID3 spec thinks it's Latin-1, so I get mojibake. What I want to do is transcode the `cp1251` into Unicode. If I was using a pen and pad, I'd look up these falsely-Unicode-coded codepoints in `cp1251`, and get the real Unicode codepoints. Perhaps you could shed some light as to why `u''.decode(enc)` has to involve an intermediate `encode(enc)` in the first place?

Comment: Because you cannot decode a `unicode` object. It is already decoded into Unicode codepoints. Unicode objects can **only** be encoded into bytestrings, and bytestrings can **only** be decoded into Unicode objects. So, why can't Python encode the mojibaked string as CP1251? Simple, it's a Unicode object, and in Unicode \xc1 is Á. But, CP1251 has no Á.

Comment: Thank you very much frb, and everyone else. This Q/A and thread has really helped me out. I feel pretty comfortable in my understanding of this now. As I understand, there were `cp1251`-encoded bytestrings in my ID3v2 tags. The tags incorrectly indicated that the bytestrings were `latin-1`. So, Mutagen takes these bytestrings, and does `{str}.decode('latin-1')`, returning a `unicode` object to me. This unicode object is mojibaked. To get the original bytestring I take the `unicode` object and encode it back into Latin-1: `{unicode}.encode('latin-1')`. Then I can do the desired `{str}.decode()`